# Ancients don't give a full level?

Tags: diablo-ii

I saved my hell ancients quest until I was level 89 with my barb and decided to use it to get to level 90. As soon as I was done, I only recieved 33% of a level at most. Is there an xp cap?

I'm asking this because I wanted to abuse this trick with my hammerdin. Wanted to level him to level 98 and use the ancients quest to get him to 99. That won't work in case the xp is capped. Or was that a bug?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not 1 level of experience, it's "a lot of experience up to 1 level".

From [quest info on Diablo 2 wiki](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Rite_of_Passage_(quest)):

> Reward: Bonus to your Experience. Normal: 1.4 million, Clvl 20 required. Nightmare: 20 million, Clvl 40 required. Hell: 40 million, Clvl 60 required. This bonus is not cut like experience from monster kills when you are past Clvl 75, so this quest is always a huge boost, but if you can save it (borrow a portal to the Worldstone Keep) until you are Clvl 80 or 85 it's even more valuable.

From [quest info on Arreat Summit](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/quests/act5.shtml):

> Reward: The maximum experience gain is limited to 1 character level.

Also, experience needed to next level on 89 is 134,011,418 ([source](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/basics/levels.shtml)). You got about 33% on 89 lvl on Hell difficulty, which is ~40kk and matches wiki info.

Comment: Look at it this way.  You receive the maximum benefit.  Someone who use the quest at a lower level and got that level bump probably wasted a portion of the XP.  You got it all, even if it didn't take you all the way to 90, it was still a major boost.

Comment: @Jammin4CO Yeah indeed. I mean its still the most logical to use it at level 98 when you don't really want to run baal (like with hammerdin). The xp gain penalty at high levels makes it nearly impossible to get any xp from normal monsters. I was just thinking that it just gave you the incredible level 98 to 99 xp.